# How to install custom client certificate and Trust it while using fiddler/Charles

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, fiddler, charles-proxy

I am trying to debug one third party mobile application, specifically network calls, When I am using fiddler and charles proxy on the first network call itself. the app shows error that client certificate on the device is not trusted and ask me to switch to mobile network instead of wifi. also when I accept the risk using the same network. The app shows that there is no internet connection.

I think the app is able to detect that the ceritificate is not the orignal client cert. and thus throwing the warning. Can I download the website or app HTTPS certificate and put it in PC as well as iPhone just like I did for fiddler root certificate.

Same issue is happening with charles proxy also.

Comment: Why not just install Charles CA in mobile device?

Comment: I have installed the Charles CA , root certificate in mobile as well, even same with fiddler. other apps are getting debug very fine, but not particular apps. They just detect on the first call. and also shows that there is no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using an iPhone, have you looked at About/Certificate Trust Settings and enabled the full trust switch after installing the (Charles) certificate?

Comment: Yes I have enabled full trust after installing the certificate. Even installed a fresh charles version. Earlier interenet was not even working when connected to proxy. but now finally it has started working, but when I start the app, it crashes on the first page itself/.

Comment: I suppose that this app is highly secured by SSL-Pinning mechanism. Basically, the app only trusts their Certificate and reject all certificates from MitM. You can read more at [SSL-Pinning - how it works](https://proxyman.io/blog/2019/11/Can-we-bypass-ssl-pinning.html)